# Form submit after ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSP page and I want to work just on the main content of the page, so when I click on some item of menu, it refreshes the main content of the page.

My main page:

```
<a onclick="formAjax()">Cartes objet de recours</a> 
<div id="page_gestion"></div>
```

My ajax call:

```
function formAjax() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'form1',
    success : function(responce) {   
            $('#page_gestion').html(responce);
        }
});
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/form1") 
public String form1(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse responce, ModelMap modelmap) {  
    model.put("lostcard", new Lostcard());
    return "form/form1" ;
}
```

My JSP page, if we can say so, that loads the main content of the main page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="lostcard" action="enregistrerLostCard"
           id="formCard_Lost">
  [...]
</form:form>
```

At this point everything is ok, but when I submit my form I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'lostcard' available as request attribute

Comment: Can you show the controller method that gets called when you submit the form?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value="/enregistrerLostCard") 
 public  
 String enregistrerLostCard() { 
  System.out.println("enregistrerLostCard"); 
  return "form/form1" ;
 }`

Comment: now i undestand i return the same form :) i didn't notice that because i want just to test. i change `return "form/form1"` and it's work. but can u tell me if my way to refresh the content page is good or there is another way to make that ?